# Fix element while scrolling through parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fix the "icon to fix" div on the right side if it is for example in the middle of the view. But it should be only fixed until the view reached the end of the red box..

At the moment I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery - How would you solve this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? If I were you I would start with bootstraps Affix http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the picture you posted and created this demo on jsBin that looks similar.  There shouldn't be a need for an entire plugin. JQuery, and some CSS, should take care of this.

http://jsbin.com/libatajure/edit?css,js,output

The meat of the code is here:

```
// Check if element totally above or totally below viewport
if (top + height - followHeight < pos || top > pos + window_height) {
  return;
}

var offset = parseInt($(window).scrollTop() - top);

if (offset > 0) {
$follow.css('transform', 'translateY('+ offset +'px)');
}
```

See how the blue element only scrolls while its parent is visible, and stops when the parent is outside the viewport?  I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an idea how to fix the follow-element in the center of the viewport instead of the top?

Comment: For everyone who wants to vertically center it: if (top + height - followHeight < pos + (window_height / 2 - followHeight / 2) || top > pos + (window_height / 2 - followHeight / 2) ) {
      return;
    }

    var offset = parseInt($(window).scrollTop() - top + (window_height / 2 - followHeight / 2));

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/gbuLykdj/1/

```
<div class="div-a"></div>

<div class="div-b">
    <div class="fixed-element"></div>
</div>

<div class="div-c"></div>
```

js

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.div-a').height() && !$('.fixed-element').hasClass('fixed')) {
        $('.fixed-element').addClass('fixed');
    } 
    else if($(window).scrollTop() < $('.div-a').height() && $('.fixed-element').hasClass('fixed')){
        $('.fixed-element').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.fixed-element').removeClass('abs');
    }
})
```

CSS

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.div-a{
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.div-b{
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.div-c{
    background:purple;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.fixed-element{
    background:#FFF;
    background:#CCC;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
.abs {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/gbuLykdj/1/

Comment: Not really. The element is fixed until the end of page.. It should have an end like: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html) is what you are looking for, there is source code on the page, too.

Comment: This is what I am searching for. Is there another way than including this big library? http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstraps-affix-scrollspy-plugins/ - The banner on the right side is also fixed the way I like to implement..